# Why does Pokemon Ultra Sun keep crashing?

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon

A few times this week, I was playing Pokemon Ultra Sun, because I wanted to catch the 37 legendary Pokemon. Because some legendary Pokemon are exclusive to Pokemon Ultra Moon, I had to use the GTS to trade with other users. What I connected to the internet, and opened up the GTS to look for some pokemon that I could trade. However, after scrolling about halfway through the list of people, both screens froze, and none of the buttons worked except for the sleep switch, and holding down the power button. The music keeps playing, though. What's going on, and how can I use the GTS again? I have had this problem around 3 times in the past week.

I am playing the game on the Nintendo 2ds system, if that helps with anything.

Comment: Is your 2DS modified in any way, and are you running an original Ultra Sun cartridge?

Comment: My 2ds is not modified, and I am running an original Ultra sun cartridge